# Disable Secureboot in Quectel SC600T

Tags: secure-boot, selinux

I have applied secure boot on my Quectel SC600T EVM Board with security Key. now I have to disable secureboot.

Is it possible back to convert from secure boot to normal boot?

Is there any way to erase my Secure Keys in SC600T EVM?

> ***> Can I disable my Secure boot?***

if yes then what steps I have to follow?

> **it is possible to upload a normal image in secure-boot EVM Board?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You have this tagged with *"windows-subsystem-for-linux"*, but your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Microsoft WSL.  If it does, kindly edit the question to include these details.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against erasing secure keys. Those could really mess up your boot in case you don't know what you're doing. All your questions will depend on your BIOS-- I've yet to see one that will not allow you to revert back/switch to non-secure boot.

As for the steps, that again depends on your BIOS.

I'm not terribly sure about your last question( *it is possible to upload a normal image in secure-boot EVM Board?*), but I don't think there should be any complications, and don't believe it will cause any irreversible problems if it can't.

Comment: Thanks, Azi-a for your reply. any other option to erase the secure key?